# Update a checkbox with a trigger

Tags: trigger, soql, query, field-update

I don't know if I'm doing it right. I have to set checkboxes values to true after import new contracts, but just for the contracts that are related to an account that already has a Contract where the EndDate of any pre-existing contract has the same StartDate of this new Contract (the checkbox of this contract has to be set to true). That is my trigger so far, how can I update these new contracts?

```
trigger testTrigger on Contract (before insert) {
List<Contract> contracts = [select EndDate from Contract where AccountId= :c.AccountId];    
    for(Contract c: Trigger.new){            
        for (Contract cs: contracts){
            if (c.StartDate == cs.EndDate){
                c.checkboxTest__c=True;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, you have a query inside a loop. Be aware this may cause issues with bulk DML operations.

Comment: Please consider completing the [Bulk Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) unit on Trailhead. Deploying this trigger may block import operations due to hitting SOQL limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before triggers only allow you to avoid DML for the records taking part in the trigger (i.e. in `trigger.new` and/or `trigger.newMap`).

Everything else still needs explicit DML.

Comment: To clarify a little bit further, you need to edit the _same in-memory instance_ of a record in `trigger.new` or `trigger.newMap`.